# How to display mm:ss format not as a DateTime, without leading zero?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2007, excel-2003, cell-formatting

We have a spreadsheet at work, and we use it to keep track of various metrics, a few having to do with call lengths. The spreadsheet has been the same for years, but we now have a call time of 51:59 (mm:ss) which has broken the old format.

I am researching how to make it work as desired, and so far the best solution is to format the cell as `[m]:ss` and enter the time in the cell  as `0:51:59`. This gives the outcome desired, and performs all the calculations correctly, except I want to be able to achieve this without the leading zero. Ideally, someone could enter `51:59` into the cell, and it would read `51:59` and not `3119:00`.

Does anyone know how to achieve what I am looking for? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am comfortable with macros, so if there is a way to achieve this with a macro that would work, but ideally I am looking for a solution without a macro.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can do this. The closest one is the following workaround:

Define cell A1 format as `hh:mm` and cell B1 format as `mm:ss`.

Enter formula `=A1/60` into B1.

This will display `51:59` in B1 when you type `51:59` into A1.

**Unfortunately, A1 text will read not-so-intuitive value after it loses the focus.**

[image]

The workaround is described here:
https://superuser.com/a/235924

Comment: Bummer. I'll just change the specific cells in question then, rather than having to train every one from here on out to add a leading zero. Thanks for your help.